# GNOME 3 extension "Icon Hider" setting location

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I would like to know where the Icon Hider extension store all settings you make. Must be a simple setting file somewhere. This are the settings:

[image: Setting image]

This is the plugin:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory (if the extension was installed locally) and look for a folder associated to the extension. Inside this folder you should find the ids and paths to `dconf`/`gsettings` schemas somewhere, most likely inside a subdirectory called "`schemas`".

Then use `dconf` or `gsettings` from command-line or the *dconf Editor* GUI application to tweak these schemas to apply various effects/functionalities provided by the extension.

Comment: Great, thank you. The exact path with `dconf` or `gsettings` is `org/gnome/shell/extensions/icon-hider`.

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me forever!