# Set up startup extensions

Tags: startup, extension

Can I actually set up a startup extension like icon hider? Every time when I reboot the computer I need to reinstall the extension.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate how you are installing icon hider. Is it the gnome extension? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 18.03 version of Ubuntu and it is a gnome exstension for hiding icons in the taskbar

Comment: If yoou installed the extension correctly, there is no reason you need to re-install it every time you start the PC. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069761/gnome-3-extension-icon-hider-setting-location